# Spinner - focus to first item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

I use dropdown spinner with cursor adapter. It contains e.g 1 - 100 items. 
I select e.g. item 50. Item is selected. Next time when I open spinner first visible row is item 50. How can I achieve that when I open spinner it will focus to first item/first visible item will be item 1?

I mean like autoscroll up in the list, so first visible item in dropdown is 1st one and not selected one.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can make the `Spinner` do what you want by extending it and overriding the two methods that are responsible for setup/showing the list of values:

```
public class CustomSpinnerSelection extends Spinner {

    private boolean mToggleFlag = true;

    public CustomSpinnerSelection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle, int mode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinnerSelection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomSpinnerSelection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSpinnerSelection(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinnerSelection(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        // this toggle is required because this method will get called in other
        // places too, the most important being called for the
        // OnItemSelectedListener
        if (!mToggleFlag) {
            return 0; // get us to the first element
        }
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // this method shows the list of elements from which to select one.
        // we have to make the getSelectedItemPosition to return 0 so you can
        // fool the Spinner and let it think that the selected item is the first
        // element
        mToggleFlag = false;
        boolean result = super.performClick();
        mToggleFlag = true;
        return result;
    }

}
```

It should work just fine for what you want to do.

Comment: I have been looking for something like this... 3 years later and it is still good info! Thanks bud.

Comment: So great!. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the selection of a Spinner to the first item like this:

```
yourspinner.setSelection(0);
```

You might want to do this in the onStart() method.

Comment: This select first item. I don't want select first item. Only scroll in spinner up to the first item, so I can see fist item in dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

This short of code will do the work for you.

```
    int prevSelection=0;
    spSunFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spTimeFromSun);
    spSunFrom.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prevSelection = spSunFrom.getSelectedItemPosition();
            spSunFrom.setSelection(0);
            return false;
        }
    });
    spSunFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(arg2==0)
                spSunFrom.setSelection(prevSelection);
            prevSelection = arg2;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            spSunFrom.setSelection(prevSelection);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice code, but not exactly what I look for. I don't want select first item. I just want scroll up to the first item. So when you open spinner, you will see first item on the top

Comment: Yes but to show the first item..there is the only way I found :)

Comment: I don't know what's the magic I need to do but it works this way in android gmail app. If you have in navigation more items that is visible on screen (e.g. in landscape mode) everytime you open spinner it will show you first item on the top