# issues in spinner layout when it have more items

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, spinner

[image: spinner data]

## I want set just 4 items at a time and other are in scroll mode in spinner

### .xml  file

```
   * <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyout_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_storage" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_database_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"   
            android:popupBackground="@color/Odoo_icon_select_1"

             />
    </LinearLayout>
```

### java file

- ```
          ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                  getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_view, list);

          spinner_adapter
  ```

  .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
              spin_database_list.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);

[image: want as like this]

Comment: Try giving fixed height to Spinner.

Comment: [have you checked this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12616250/3663329)??

Comment: The question is already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426038/how-do-i-set-the-maximum-length-for-a-spinners-drop-down-list

Comment: Look at this lib code https://github.com/ankitthakkar/DropDownSpinner

Comment: sir, i dont want library  pls help in code ..because i am beginner and started android just 2 month. so pls help in code.@PankajKumar ,@Remees M Syde

Comment: Well you are new to android, android does not provide such functionality, you need to create your own implementation of Spinner by extending spinner class, follow the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238513/android-limit-the-no-of-items-displayed-in-a-spinners-dropdown-list