# Custom spinner drop-down showing data from bottom first time

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-spinner

I have create a spinner and set data using custom adapter. In that case, If I click on spinner I am getting drop-down which start from bottom. I need that drop down start from top.

I am getting this issue as shown in image

[image]

As shown in image Data getting from bottom when I click on spinner first time.

I need to get data from top.

My code :

Spinner and adapter setting

```
listCtcLakhs = new ArrayList<String>();


        listCtcLakhs.add("25");
        listCtcLakhs.add("30");
        listCtcLakhs.add("35");
        listCtcLakhs.add("40");
        listCtcLakhs.add("45");
        listCtcLakhs.add("50");
        listCtcLakhs.add("60");
        listCtcLakhs.add("70");
        listCtcLakhs.add("80");
        listCtcLakhs.add("90");
        listCtcLakhs.add("100");
        listCtcLakhs.add("110");
        listCtcLakhs.add("120");
        listCtcLakhs.add("150");
        listCtcLakhs.add("Lacs");

        spForCtcLakhs
                .setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), listCtcLakhs));

        spForCtcLakhs.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.iconDropDown)
                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        spForCtcLakhs.setSelection(listCtcLakhs.size() - 1);
```

Adapter Code

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> dropDownList;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> studentList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.dropDownList = studentList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(dropDownList.size()>1){


            return dropDownList.size()-1;
        }
        return dropDownList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return dropDownList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtMenu;
        ImageView ivDropDown;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (view == null) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.highest_qulifi_layout,
                    parent, false);

            holder.txtMenu = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.highest_quilification_textview);

            holder.ivDropDown = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.iconDropDown);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        try {

            String name = dropDownList.get(position);
            // set hint
            if (position == getCount()) {
                holder.ivDropDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.txtMenu.setText(name);
            }

            // Set data
            else {

                holder.txtMenu.setText(name);
            }


        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

I have tried lots of way but I could not set hint on top of list (In list hint is on bottom and I am setting it with `setSelection()`). Because of that it is not coming on top.

Please help me if someone have any other way to do this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the dropdown starts showing the next items from the one selected. I believe you need to create a CustomSpinner class to override the methods in the Spinner class that determine what the dropdown shows. This other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528510/spinner-focus-to-first-item) contains a pretty clear example of a possible implementation.